# SQL Server: Determine which views are actually used

Tags: sql-server

I try to find out which views are actually being used on a very large database which thousands of views, most of them probably obsolete. After several unsuccessful attempts which involves extended events, I came to the conclusion that the best (in terms of reability as well as low performance impact) way to do this is to run the query below every 15 seconds and store the results in another table.

```
select a.attribute,a.value as objectId, object_name(convert(int,a.value))
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p
outer apply sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(p.plan_handle) a
outer apply sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(p.plan_handle) a1
where p.objtype='View' 
and a.attribute='objectid' and a.value>0 
and a1.attribute='dbid' and a1.value=DB_ID()
```

What do you experts think about this approach? In my tests, this seems to work well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39596/sql-server-how-to-detect-unused-views-and-or-get-usage-stats#39607

Comment: @RuudHelderman I'm aware of this article, however I think since we neither use option(recompile) nor the option  for ad hoc workloads, this doesn't apply here.